# Problems running java in notepad++

Tags: java, notepad++

I'm trying to compile and run a java program in notepad++ and I get error code 2, the system cannot find the file specified.

Here is my program code:

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("It worked!!!!!");
    }
}
```

And I'm attempting to run and compile it using

```
javac "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
java -classpath "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)" "$(NAME_PART)"
```

Here's the link to the the page where I found this: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/113551-compilingrunning-java-programs-in-notepad/

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: And you are not using an IDE because...?

Comment: Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314027/using-notepad-to-compile-java-code

Comment: @PeterLawrey I am not using an IDE because I am trying to simulate working on a Linux system as I have to in my Computer Science course where we only have access to text editors.

Comment: @WernerVesterås I have read over that page, but the only solution was to switch to netbeans, which is not what I want. I have followed the steps on http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/courses/compsci101s1c/resources/Notepad/Notepad++.pdf and I still get the same error.

Comment: I use an IDE on linux every day, but if thats all you have and you don't even have maven, I guess you have no choice.

Comment: Not that it matters here, but class names should start with a capital letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

javac isn't available on your path.  Can you execute `javac -version` from a command line?  I would expect that you get the message:

```
'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file.
```

You can add the fully qualified path to your `javac` and `java` commands above, or you can add the java bin directory to your path.

Comment: Entering `javac -version` did result in your expected output. How would I add the fully qualified path to my javac and java commands?

Comment: `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_33\bin\javac.exe" "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"` (actual path should be wherever you have the JDK installed)